# Why is modification of the program counter not a privileged instruction?

Tags: operating-system, privileges, instructions, program-counter

The program counter is stored in the PCB and that is in the kernel space. But modifying the program counter is not a privileged instruction. Why is that?

Comment: The PCB is only updated when the process stops running; it isn't kept in sync with the register value while a task is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to modify the program counter every time you call a procedure and return from one.

Comment: ..or when executing any branch, jump, loop, switch, conditional or similar construct that can change flow-of-control.